# Matrix, Kernel and Span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Q. if $A$ be a $n\times n$ be a matrix. if $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has trivial solution, does it imply columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

A. No, The equation always has trivial solution.

Is not it that if the $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has trivial solutions equivalent to saying that columns are linearly independent? and hence span $\mathbb{R}$, more precisely, $A\not=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be tripping up over language. There's a very big difference between

> $Ax = 0$ has the trivial solution

and

> $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution

The latter is also equivalent to

> The solution to $Ax = 0$ is trivial

if by "solution" one implicitly means the "complete solution".

Comment: yes. thanks. merely matter of language. thanks.

Comment: What does your comment mean? Yes the question was "has _only_ trivial solution"? If so then you have two answers already, don't forget to mark one of them as such :)

Answer (score 1):

If the only solution is the trivial solution, then the n columns and are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^n$ furthermore the linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(x) = Ax$ is a bijection, the determinant of the matrix $A$ is nonzero and there are probably 20 more things that are equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I've misunderstood, but if $x$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $Ax = 0$ for all $n \ \text{x} \ n$ matrices $A$. So it isn't true, because if it were, it's essentially implying that all $n \ \text{x} \ n$ matrices $A$ have linearly independent columns (and rows) which isn't true.